# Is this a correct recursive sequence definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

Take this definition:

[image]

Is this definition of $s_k$ for $k\ge2$ correct?

$s_k=6a_{k-1}-5a_{k-2}$ but where does the $a$ term come from?

The book swaps $a$ and $s$ interchangeably.

Comment: Looks like a typo, unless a specific sequence $(a_n)$ is explicitly intended.

Comment: For reference, first 20 values:
0
4
24
124
624
3124
15624
78124
390624
1953124
9765624
48828124
244140624
1220703124
6103515624
30517578124
152587890624
762939453124
3814697265624
19073486328124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $(a_k)_k$ sequence is well-defined there is nothing wrong with that definition. You should give us more details on $(a_k)_k$ if you want some more help.

If $a$ were to be replaced by $s$ in the definition, it would still be correct.

Comment: No other sequence is defined. I suppose $a_k$ by convention refers to the current sequence you are dealing with?

Comment: There is no such convention, I think it's just a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a typo for $s$, as the comments say, this can be solved. Define the generating function $S(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} s_n z^n$. Reorganize the recurrence so there are no subtractions in indices:
$$
s_{n + 2} = 6 s_{n + 1} - 5 s_n
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} s_{n + 1} z^n &= \frac{S(z) - s_0}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} s_{n + 2} z^n &= \frac{S(z) - s_0 -s_1 z}{z^2}
\end{align}
to end up with:
$$
\frac{S(z) - 4 z}{z^2} = 6 \frac{S(z)}{z} - 5 S(z)
$$
Solving for $S(z)$, as partial fractions:
$$
S(z) = \frac{1}{1 - 5 z} - \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
s(n) = 5^n - 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been concluded that there was a typo, I'll offer an eigenvalue solution as an alternative to a generating function. So we have $\lambda^{2} - 6\lambda + 5 = 0$. This gives us eigenvalues of $\lambda = 1, 5$.

We then set up our general form equation: $s_{k} = A + B * 5^{k}$.

Solving $s_{0} = 0 = A + B$, we get $A = -B$.

Then we solve $s_{1} = -B + 5B = 4$, so $B = 1$.

And so $s_{k} = 5^{k} - 1$, the same solution given by the generating function.